Tab key bug at the beginning of lines in VS Code
I'm experiencing a strange issue in Visual Studio Code. When I press the tab key at the beginning of all lines in my code, it creates a space and then immediately removes it. This problem doesn't occur when I press the tab key in the middle of a line; it only happens at the start.
Here's what I've tried so far:
I don't have any extensions that should affect this behaviour.
My VS Code is up to date with the latest version.
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code, but the issue persists.
Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Guide here: Keybinding Issues · microsoft/vscode Wiki. I got there from bug report > Submitting Bugs and Suggestions

Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled command in the command palette)? If not, then do an extension bisect to figure out what extension is causing it.
